# Sangria not seeing GraphQL query variables

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

When I have a query like this:

```
{
  "query": "mutation { createInventory(name: $name, schema: $schema) }",
  "variables": {
    "name": "i1",
    "schema": "s"
  }
}
```

I get an error back: *Variable '$name' is not defined.*

I checked those variables were being extracted from JSON properly, and they were. To be sure, I tried explicitly passing in the `name` variable when I execute the query:

```scala
Executor.execute(
    GraphQLSchema.schema,
    query,
    ctx,
    variables = InputUnmarshaller.mapVars(Map("name" -> "foo"))
)
```

Why would Sangria not be recognizing these variables? Is there something wrong with how I'm naming them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the "variable definition" section of the GraphQL query itself. This is a part of the query which indicates the types of variables it expects to be passed in.

So this should work, provided I've guessed the right types for the variables:

```
{
  "query": "mutation myMutation($name: String, $schema: String) { createInventory(name: $name, schema: $schema) }",
  "variables": {
    "name": "i1",
    "schema": "s"
  }
}
```

Read more in my article, [The Anatomy of a GraphQL Query](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/the-anatomy-of-a-graphql-query-6dffa9e9e747).

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty much a perfect SO answer: fixed the problem, answered quickly, and linked to an article explaining in more depth.